# confusion about output from getorientation function

Tags: android, orientation, sensors

According to the official post,
X is defined as the vector product Y.Z (It is tangential to the ground at the device's current location and roughly **points West**).
Y is tangential to the ground at the device's current location and points towards the magnetic **North Pole**.
Z points towards the center of the Earth and is perpendicular to the ground.

Y is related to the Roll, X is related to Pitch, Z is related to Azimuth.

So, it is reasonable to think that the rotation could lead to Pitch's readings change when you hold the phone flat in direction to the north will be the same rotation that leads to Roll's readings change when you hold the phone in direction to the east, Right? In other words, the actual rotation leading to Pitch angle changing in phone's coordinate system will result in roll reading change in the coordinate system that getorientation function are using when you hold the phone in the direction of east.

**However**, it seems to me that it is not that case when I see the readings on the screen. When I hold the phone flatly in direction to the east, the actual Pitch rotation action in phone's coordinate system will still result in the 'pitch reading changing' for getorientation function. Plz help me with that!! Thank you so much in advance!

Here is the code I am using:

```
    package com.example.yang.euler;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private SensorManager sm;
    private Sensor aSensor;
    private Sensor mSensor;
    public EditText Azimuth;
    public EditText Pitch;
    public EditText Roll;

float[] accelerometerValues = new float[3];
float[] magneticFieldValues = new float[3];


@Override
public View findViewById(int id) {
    return super.findViewById(id);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    aSensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    sm.registerListener(myListener, aSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sm.registerListener(myListener, mSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    calculateOrientation();

}

public void onPause(){
    sm.unregisterListener(myListener);
    super.onPause();
}


final SensorEventListener myListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            magneticFieldValues = sensorEvent.values.clone();
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY)
            accelerometerValues = sensorEvent.values.clone();
        calculateOrientation();
    }
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}
};


private  void calculateOrientation() {
    Azimuth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editazimuth);
    Pitch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpitch);
    Roll = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editroll);
    float[] values = new float[3];
    float[] R = new float[9];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, null, accelerometerValues, magneticFieldValues);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(R, values);
    values[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[0]);
    values[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[1]);
    values[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[2]);
    Azimuth.setText(values[0]+"");
    Pitch.setText(values[1]+"");
    Roll.setText(values[2]+"");
}}
```